# Get all table names in a Django app

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

How to get all table names in a Django app?

I use the following code but it doesn't get the tables created by ManyToManyField

```
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
app = get_app(app_name)
for model in get_models(app):
    print model._meta.db_table
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**This will give you all of the table names, like the OP asks for:**

```
from django.apps import apps

tables = [m._meta.db_table for c in apps.get_app_configs() for m in c.get_models()]
```

**This will give you all model names:**

```
from django.db import connection
tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)
```

**This will give you all of the model names on a per app basis:**

```
from django.apps import apps 
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered 

app_models = apps.get_app_config('my_app').get_models()
```

**Additional reading**

And yet another recommends reading this answer:

[Django get list of models in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702772/django-get-list-of-models-in-application/31184258#answer-39661207)

Comment: Edited to include the mechanism to get only the installed apps models. I really recommend looking at the syncdb command code.

Comment: This answer lists all the tables that my django has ever used, including those created by apps that were once in INSTALLED_APPS but no longer are.    Is there a way to find out the ones that are currently relevant?

Comment: For future references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184258/1937033 

From Django 1.7 on, you can use this code, for example in your admin.py to register all models: `from django.apps import apps  from django.contrib import admin from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered
app_models = apps.get_app_config('my_app').get_models()
for model in app_models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except AlreadyRegistered:
        pass`

Comment: @ThePhi I added that to the answer. Haven't tested though.

Comment: it works by my testing, 1.11. However, note that `app_models` is an iterable that you can only iterate through once, so maybe best to do `app_models = list(app_models)` for durability.

Comment: You can list all table names via: 
```[ m._meta.db_table for c in apps.get_app_configs() for m in c.get_models() ]```

Comment: Thanks @cdosborn, nice and effective. Plus, it gives the list of tables, not the models. For getting the list of models I liked better the `dict(apps.all_models['<app_name>'])` found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702772/django-get-list-of-models-in-application/31184258#answer-39661207  (both tested in django 2.2)

Comment: @cethegeek, Clean & tidy! where to find the document/manual for `connection.introspection`, please?

Comment: @NegaOverflow, to my knowledge such documentation doesn't exist. But you can read the code (for mysql) here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py and for other databases start here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends and navigate to your known backend and open introspection.py. Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest answer, that still allows you to pick which app you want, is to modify your code with one extra argument "include_auto_created".

```
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
app = get_app(app_name)
for model in get_models(app, include_auto_created=True):
    print model._meta.db_table
```

Obviously I got this by following celope's advice to read the syncdb source, so thanks for that - just documenting an exact answer that includes the app name as it was what I wanted and possibly others too in future.

Answer (score 2):

This works for

```
>>> python -m django version
2.0.7
```

OK, here's how you do that:

```
>>> from django.apps import apps 
>>> polls_tables = apps.get_app_config("polls")
>>> polls_tables.models
OrderedDict([('question', <class 'polls.models.Question'>), ('choice', <class 'polls.models.Choice'>), ('reporter', <class 'polls.models.Reporter'>), ('article', <class 'polls.models.Article'>), ('publication', <class 'polls.models.Publication'>), ('publicationarticle_publications', <class 'polls.models.PublicationArticle_publications'>), ('publicationarticle', <class 'polls.models.PublicationArticle'>), ('person', <class 'polls.models.Person'>), ('group', <class 'polls.models.Group'>), ('membership', <class 'polls.models.Membership'>), ('place', <class 'polls.models.Place'>), ('restaurant', <class 'polls.models.Restaurant'>), ('waiter', <class 'polls.models.Waiter'>), ('student', <class 'polls.models.Student'>), ('assembler', <class 'polls.models.Assembler'>), ('bike', <class 'polls.models.Bike'>), ('blog', <class 'polls.models.Blog'>), ('author', <class 'polls.models.Author'>), ('entry_authors', <class 'polls.models.Entry_authors'>), ('entry', <class 'polls.models.Entry'>), ('themeblog', <class 'polls.models.ThemeBlog'>), ('bookauthor', <class 'polls.models.BookAuthor'>), ('publisher', <class 'polls.models.Publisher'>), ('book_authors', <class 'polls.models.Book_authors'>), ('book', <class 'polls.models.Book'>), ('store_books', <class 'polls.models.Store_books'>), ('store', <class 'polls.models.Store'>), ('dummy', <class 'polls.models.Dummy'>)])
>>> polls_tables.models.keys()
odict_keys(['question', 'choice', 'reporter', 'article', 'publication', 'publicationarticle_publications', 'publicationarticle', 'person', 'group', 'membership', 'place', 'restaurant', 'waiter', 'student', 'assembler', 'bike', 'blog', 'author', 'entry_authors', 'entry', 'themeblog', 'bookauthor', 'publisher', 'book_authors', 'book', 'store_books', 'store', 'dummy'])
```

you can also get field names of particular model

```
>>> questionTable = polls_tables.get_model("question")
>>> questionTable._meta.get_fields()
(<ManyToOneRel: polls.choice>, <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.CharField: question_text>, <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: pub_date>)
```

Further if you want you can get count of it by

```
>>> len(questionTable._meta.get_fields())
4
```

To get all the values in database, you can do it as:

```
>>> list = [entry for entry in Entry.objects.values()]
>>> for dict in list:
...     print()
...     for key in dict:
...             print(key," : ", dict[key]) 
... 

id  :  1
blog_id  :  5
headline  :  i have blog entry named DJANGO
pub_date  :  2018-06-10
n_comments  :  5
n_pingbacks  :  1

id  :  2
blog_id  :  5
headline  :  i have blog entry named DJANGO
pub_date  :  2018-06-10
n_comments  :  7
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method should be to use the database reflection APIs in django to go directly to the database. The drawback to this is that it won't give you any tables before you've synced.